# Linking two attributes in a table

Tags: sql

I'm creating a mock drivers registrar for an intro to SQL class and am not sure how to ensure that two attributes of a table are always linked.  The table represents a relationship between a Person entity and a Vehicle entity --- the relationship is called Owns.

I have it set so that many people can own any number of vehicles and any number of people can be considered owners/drivers for that vehicle.  However, when a ticket is issued by a traffic camera, the ticket should be issued to the primary owner/driver, which I have as an attribute of the relationship.

My SQL code for the Owns table is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE Owns (
Owned_By INT,
VIN INT,
Primary INT,
FOREIGN KEY(Owned_BY) REFERENCES Person(SIN),
FOREIGN KEY(VIN) REFERENCES Vehicle(VIN),
FOREIGN KEY(Primary) REFERENCES Person(SIN));
```

I'd like to make it so that the VIN only has one Primary but can have multiple Owned_By.  Can I accomplish this using a CHECK or do I need to use something else?

Answer (score 0):

2 tables:

1. vehicle (VIN int, PRIMART int, ... others vehicle unique props)
   FOREIGN KEY(Primary) REFERENCES Person(SIN));
2. owns (OWNED_BY int, VIN int) FOREIGN KEY(VIN) REFERENCES
   Vehicle(VIN), FOREIGN KEY(Owned_BY) REFERENCES Person(SIN);

Comment: Based on my ER diagram, a vehicle can exist in the database without being owned by anyone.  So wouldn't having Primary as an attribute of the vehicle be incorrect?

Comment: it should allow nulls, so null value mean no primary owner